# How to change width and height of an absolute positioned image placed in a div by css :before

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place an image in a div using css:before with position:absolute; there is already an image in that div. Why I can't control the height or width of that absolute positioned image?

css:

```
div:before{
    content:url('buble.png');
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    z-index:200;
}
```

html:

```
<div><img src="profile_pic.png" alt="" /></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Explanation :**

You won't be able to apply Css properties to the image if you place it in the content of the `:before` pseudo element. the `width/height` you set apply only to the pseudo element and not on it's content.

**Solution :**

Set the image as background of the `:before` pseudo element. Then you can use `background-size` property to size the image as desired.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/hF5KK/)**

As explained in [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) specs, you can use percentages to size the image or values like `cover/contain`. You can also position, center horizontaly/verticaly your image using [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position).

CSS :

```
div {position:relative;width:350px;}
div:before{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    background-image : url('buble.png');
    background-size:contain;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:200;
}
```

Comment: your fiddle link is broken. please check.

Comment: @bandedKrait Thx for pointing that out, I often forget to click "update". Link fixed.

Answer (score 0):

[You cannot change the dimensions of the image when inserted this way](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/content/). As others have mentioned, you may use `background-image` on the generated content instead.